# Return Cursor object from DatabaseManager?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need some advice/help. I have a MainActivity and a DatabaseManager class. I'm not sure how to handle the data from the DatabaseManager to the MainActivity?

I need to read some data in the DatabaseManager and then return it to the MainActivty and then pass the data to and another activity that has a ListView.

To begin, should I return the Cursor object from the DatabaseManager and then use adapter to get the data to the ListView or how do I get it to the MainActivity? Can I iterate each row in the table and return each column as a string? Or should I add it to a ArrayList and then return that? Preciate some help!

Example in code is preciated!

Comment: *Example in code is preciated!* - How exactly do you expect someone to provide code examples when all you have mentioned in your question related to your code is that you have two classes?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method in the DatabaseHandler called "getMyGenericData(parameterIWishToUse)" (I have no idea what data your database is storing).

Then in your DatabaseHandler do this (Implement your own objects instead of mine generic once):

```
public ArrayList<MyGenericItem> getAllVisistedEntries() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<MyGenericItem> myGenericItems = new ArrayList<MyGenericItem>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM MY_GENERIC_TABLE";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {

        MyGenericItem mgi = new MyGenericItem();
        mgi.setValueOne(cursor.getString(0));
        mgi.setValueTwo(cursor.getString(1));
        // ETC....
       myGenericItems.add(myGenericItem);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

    return myGenericItems;
}
```